# Ubuntu 22.04 dual network configuration, WAN / LAM

Tags: networking, server, mount, nfs

I have a server with two network interfaces.
One network interface is connected to a public IP. This is a Web server. All is working.

I want to configure the 2nd network interface with a private IP, let's say 10.0.0.*, to connect to a NAS either through a network switch or ideally directly over a cross-over ethernet cable (I don't know if any of the network interfaces, server or NAS, are auto-sensing). The ultimate goal is to have the NAS mounted as NFS.

What is the best way to achieve this, and still have the Web server (and all the other needs to connect to the Web) continue to work correctly?

Thank you, all.